# Functionality of likes using cookies

Tags: laravel

Let's say I have a `like` field in my model, now I want to make the functionality of adding a like using Cookie. For example, we have an article ID, we check in cookies, if there is no data, then we add like and set the time for 10 hours, for example, and so on, 10 hours pass, we check and again we can add like and set this time again. If the data is already there, then we do not add like and do not update the time.

Can anyone see some examples of this? Or where to start and how to implement it?

I read the documentation but did not quite understand how it should work

Let's get a value with a like field

```
$likes = Request::cookie('like');
```

Choosing the time

```
$minutes = 600;
```

And what's next, how can I make a check to add a like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your updated_at column is not updated automatically on update (Eloquent do this by default), you need to do it, so the query can filter the row with correct time for update. You can use Carbon for easy time calculations.

```
 $likes = Request::cookie('like');
 $hours = 10;
    if($likes) {
        # Eloquent way
        Article::find($id)
            ->where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subHours($hours)->toDateTimeString())
            ->increment('like');
    }
```

If you want Query Builder way use this syntax:

```
# Query Builder way
DB::table('articles')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subHours($hours)->toDateTimeString())
    ->increment('like');
```

Not tested.

Comment: Cool! Thank you. There is one more question, how to implement this in php.blade, I suppose I have a disabled (true, false) button, how can I make it like it if true, and if false, remove it

Comment: You can't implement this in blade.php. There you can use some javascript to enable/disable button based on what time is now compared to last updated_at in the database or just check this on page loading with php only and set the button state. It's up to you.

Comment: And then how can I make sure that when clicked, a like is added?

Comment: You must implement it through ajax request or page submit/reload. They both should point to PHP code in the answer. It will increment likes only if where statements are satisfied. So no update will be made if time is less than 10 hours. If likes are incremented, the updated_at column is updated too with the actual timestamp, so you will be in this window of 10 hours that you don't want to enable the button. You need to compare updated_at an actual time constantly, to know when to allow next like.